# How do I destructure this JSON data in React.js

Tags: reactjs, json

```
Object.keys(col).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {Object.keys(col[item]).map((subitem, i) => {
                return <div key={i}>{subitem}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

So basically I need to access the value since this a I had to use Object.method but I can only access key. This is the data i am working on

```
"Time Series (5min)": {
    "2021-08-11 19:15:00": {
        "1. open": "142.1999",
        "2. high": "142.1999",
        "3. low": "142.1999",
        "4. close": "142.1999",
        "5. volume": "200"
    },
    "2021-08-11 16:30:00": {
        "1. open": "142.5000",
        "2. high": "142.5000",
        "3. low": "142.5000",
        "4. close": "142.5000",
        "5. volume": "160"
    },
```

Comment: You never use `subitem`

Comment: @AndyRay have it just displays "1. open" and other keys in that pair but not the values part.

Comment: That's because you only use the key, you don't log `col[item][subitem]`

Comment: @AndyRay Thank you so much I guess I had wrong approach to this Object.keys was returning keys only not the whole list so I had to use full notation to access it

Comment: check out [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)